# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when calling reloaddata from segment

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol, reloaddata

I have segment control with 3 segments initially it displays data in tableview. When i click on the other segment it gives me this exception. Really hard to figure out what is the problem. I can post the code if requested.

```
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:
0x192308c:  movl   8(%esp), %ecx
0x1923090:  movl   4(%esp), %eax
0x1923094:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x1923096:  je     0x19230e8                 ; objc_msgSend + 92
0x1923098:  movl   (%eax), %edx
0x192309a:  pushl  %edi
0x192309b:  movl   8(%edx), %edi     <-------HERE 
0x192309e:  pushl  %esi
0x192309f:  movl   (%edi), %esi
0x19230a1:  movl   %ecx, %edx
0x19230a3:  shrl   $2, %edx
0x19230a6:  andl   %esi, %edx
0x19230a8:  movl   8(%edi,%edx,4), %eax
0x19230ac:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x19230ae:  je     0x19230b9                 ; objc_msgSend + 45
0x19230b0:  cmpl   (%eax), %ecx
0x19230b2:  je     0x19230d0                 ; objc_msgSend + 68
0x19230b4:  addl   $1, %edx
0x19230b7:  jmp    0x19230a6                 ; objc_msgSend + 26
0x19230b9:  popl   %esi
0x19230ba:  popl   %edi
0x19230bb:  movl   4(%esp), %edx
0x19230bf:  movl   (%edx), %eax
```

My Segment switch method. Its Segment 1 which is the one not working.

```
- (IBAction)segmentSwitch:(id)sender
{
  NSInteger selectedSegment = [sender selectedSegmentIndex];

  if(selectedSegment == 0)
  {

    [tableview1 reloadData];
  }
  if(selectedSegment == 1)
  {
    NSLog(@"Above reloaddata");
    [tableview1 reloadData];
    NSLog(@"Below reloaddata");
  }
  if(selectedSegment == 2)
  {
    UIAlertView *save = [[[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Alert!"
                          message:@"No Data Found"
                          delegate:self
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                          otherButtonTitles: nil] autorelease];
    [save show];
 }
}
```

TableView Delegates

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if(tableView == tableview1){
    NSInteger selectedSegment = segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
    if(selectedSegment == 0)
        return arraycontacts.count;
    if(selectedSegment == 1)
    {
         return phPatch.count; 
    }


 }
 else
    return 0;
 }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

if(cell==nil)
{
    cell= [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"]autorelease];

}

if(tableView == tableview1){

    NSInteger selectedSegment = segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex;

    if(selectedSegment == 0){
        NSLog(@"In segment 0");

        cell.textLabel.text=[arraycontacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        UILabel *typeLabel = [[[UILabel alloc]init]autorelease];
        typeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        typeLabel.text = [arraypatch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        typeLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        typeLabel.frame = CGRectMake(300,2.0f,150,50);
        [cell addSubview:typeLabel];


        UILabel *typeLabel1 = [[[UILabel alloc]init]autorelease];
        typeLabel1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        typeLabel1.text = [arrayclass objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        typeLabel1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        typeLabel1.frame = CGRectMake(400,2.0f,150,50);
        [cell addSubview:typeLabel1];


        UILabel *typeLabel2 = [[[UILabel alloc]init]autorelease];
        typeLabel2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        typeLabel2.text = [arrayspeciality objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        typeLabel2.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        typeLabel2.frame = CGRectMake(500,2.0f,250,50);
        [cell addSubview:typeLabel2];


        UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(770,2.0f,250,50)] autorelease];
        UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(10,0, 150, 40);
        [btn setTitle:@"Precall" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(precallClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [headerView addSubview:btn];
        [cell addSubview:headerView];

        cell.tag = indexPath.row;

    }

   if(selectedSegment == 1){

       NSLog(@"In segment 1");

       cell.textLabel.text=[phPatch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        UILabel *typeLabel = [[[UILabel alloc]init]autorelease];
        typeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        typeLabel.text = [phName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        typeLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        typeLabel.frame = CGRectMake(300,2.0f,150,50);
        [cell addSubview:typeLabel];

        UILabel *typeLabel1 = [[[UILabel alloc]init]autorelease];
        typeLabel1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        typeLabel1.text = [phClass objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        typeLabel1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        typeLabel1.frame = CGRectMake(400,2.0f,150,50);
        [cell addSubview:typeLabel1];


    }   
   }
   return cell;
  }
```

Thank You.

Comment: please show the related code.. the assembler code from the objC runtime doesnt help

Comment: Please post some real, understandable code. Your comment _<-------HERE_ is not useful at all. Thats just a `movl` instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. The problem was in

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
if(tableView == tableview1){

    NSInteger selectedSegment = segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
    if(selectedSegment == 0)
        return @"               Doctor                                    Patch          Class                    Speciality";
    else                          <------ This Else was not there, the reason is was giving BAD ACCESS ERROR.
        return @""; 
}
  else
    return @"         Patch                     Pharmacy Name               Class";
}
```

Anyway, thanx.

Answer (score 0):

The assembly code does not help a lot.

YOu are getting this because you are sending a message to a released object.

To debug bad access things you instead of run, just do profile and then choose zombie objects.

That keeps all the objects in memory and should show you where your bug is coming from.